# different error message than the one from a programming book

Tags: python

Recently, I started to read-through Al Sweigart's book, Automate The Boring Stuff with Python". I downloaded the same Python (maybe a little more up to date) that the book told me to download. In an example for an error that can come up that the book gives, it shows a certain error message. The error message is at the following link (since it is in a book, I simply took a picture of it):

[image]

Whenever I try that code in my Python, though, I get the following:

```
>>> 5 +
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 42 + 5 +* 2
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I actually keep getting errors that are not written the same. Is it due to maybe the older version of Python? I tried googling, but I couldn't find why.

Thank you!

Comment: You sure about using the same Python version in the book?

Comment: How are you running Python? If you just run `python` in your terminal/cmd/etc., syntax errors should include the caret pointing at the error, as in the book. That should be true whether you have 3.7, 3.2, 2.4. (Maybe not 0.9 or something, but I doubt that's the issue…)

Comment: @DyZ I think it's pretty reasonable to care that you don't get file, line, statement, and caret included in your syntax errors. For a trivial case like this, it may not matter, but trying to debug larger programs, that's going to be a serious pain. (There's a reason Python includes this, after all.) Plus, if that's not working right, I'll bet tracebacks for other exceptions are screwy as well. Definitely something worth diagnosing.

Comment: What do you use as the shell? Command-line terminal, IDLE, Spyder? And what does Python report when you start it? Like 'Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56)...'?

Comment: @abarnert Agree, silly me.

Comment: Actually, scratch what I said above; [even in Python 0.9 you got this information](https://gist.github.com/abarnert/6ffc8b6cf51adcbe647339eacd7b6d9f). Pretty impressive REPL for 1991.

Comment: @DyZ Good point on IDLE. IIRC (I haven't used it in forever…), it captures the SyntaxError and highlights the line in-place, instead of letting it show the error information normally?

Comment: @RamazanPolat I mean, I have Python 3.6.4, and the book wanted said to get the latest version (they use 3.4, I believe). I'm not sure how much of a difference then there should be.

Comment: @abarnert I am running it through the Python 3.6.4 shell (comes up when I open IDLE).

Comment: @DyZ I use IDLE, and it returns the following:

    Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>>

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that you’re using the IDLE IDE instead of running the interpreter in your terminal.

IDLE parses error messages to highlight the offending code in red, directly on the input prompt, so it doesn’t need to copy the code and point at it with a caret. It’s just a different (and hopefully even better) way of presenting the same information.

If you don’t like this, don’t use IDLE. Instead, open your terminal program (it’s called `cmd` on Windows, but the Start Menu name for it may be something different, like “Command Prompt), and run Python there (usually by typing `python3` if you’re on macOS or Linux, or `py` if you’re on Windows). You won’t get the nice IDE features (and you’ll need a separate text editor—anything but Notepad or TextEdit will do—later on when you get to writing scripts and modules), but you’ll be doing exactly the same thing the book is showing you.

Comment: Hi,

Awesome! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Spyder and the command-line version of Python (one of which is presumably used in the book that you mention), IDLE (that you use) employs a different form of error reporting:

[image]

The location of the error is shown with a pink rectangle. So, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Hi!

Awesome. Thanks so much!